# Unity не отображает текст

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

Unity не отображает текст. Ни в редакторе, ни после компиляции. Использую Unity 2019.3.7а1
Я вижу следующие.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробывал переустанавливать editor но это ни к чему не привело. Как исправить это?
PS unity-editor установлен через Hub на Arch Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить unity-editor самостоятельно, не через Hub

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй изменить размер текста, его цвет и шрифт, версия баганая, все может быть, и если у тебя text mesh pro, то поставь на дэфолт.

Comment: В новой версии такого бага уже нет

Answer (score 2):

Не ставьте сырые движки это будет проблематично в будущем работе, скачивайте стабильные версии LTS

https://unity3d.com/ru/unity/qa/lts-releases?_ga=2.227122011.771448270.1605034366-1226039014.1600094653

Answer (score 2):

На Arch-подобные советую ставить Unity через flatpak: Все работает без збоев

Answer (score 1):

Знаешь, есть несколько факторов. Например,

Размер текста - если у тебя слишком маленькое поле и большой размер текста, то он просто не будет отображать текст(я обычно нажимаю Beast fit, так он будет сам выставлять размер текста под размер рамки).

Позиция канваса от камеры. Если он не входит в границы камеры, то и текста не будет видно. Это распространяется только на игру.

факторов которые будут влиять на то, будет ли отображаться текст в самой игре много, но про отображение в редакторе знаю только размер текста(шрифта)

Как итог, я ссылаюсь на размер текста, так как сам на такое часто попадался.